# How to import a json file in a Vue.js single file component with Webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-4

## Important

The problem was a file in the wrong directory. This will likely not help you...

## The question

I'm using Vue.js single file components and want to import a `.json` file in one of them but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's what I want to do:

`src/App.vue` contains:

```
import data from './tree.json'; // This does not work!

export default {
  /* Component def */
};
```

Webpack then gives the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './tree.json' in 'C:\src'
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 8:0-31
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi ./src/app.js
```

Webpack configuration (simplified):

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  entry: [
    './src/app.js',
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I am using Vue.js 2.5 and Webpack 4.28.

Trying to import the same `.json` file in a "vanilla" `.js` file however **does work**:

```
// In src/app.js
import data from './tree.json';
```

This leads me to think there is something specific to the `vue-loader` that doesn't work with Webpack's native handling of `.json` imports, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Are you sure your `tree.json` file and your `App.vue` file are in the same folder?

Comment: you should be able to import without `.json` extension, permitted that the file is on the same folder (same comment as above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that it's looking for your tree.json file inside your src/ directory.   If it's not there than that is your problem.

```
⚠️ Since webpack >= v2.0.0, importing of JSON files will work by default. You might still want to use this if you use a custom file extension. See the v1.0.0 -> v2.0.0 Migration Guide for more information
```

Basically, your problem has to do with the file not being in the right directory.

Comment: Wow! - I follow you on youtube! - :D - keep up the good work!

Comment: I know that webpack is supposed to handle json files *and it does*. As stated in the question, I'm able to load the json file from a **vanilla** .js file instead of from a .vue file.

Comment: Did you add .json to your webpack resolve extensions?

Comment: I had a feeling :)